# Best file formats for S3 using Spark for ETL on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, etl

We are planning to perform ETL processing using Spark with source data sitting on S3. The data volume for ETL processing is less than 100 million. What is the best format to store data in S3 in this scenario i.e. the best compression and file format (text, sequence, parquet etc.)

Answer (score 0):

ORC or Parquet for queries, compressed with Snappy. Avro is another general purpose format, but way less efficient for SparkSQL queries as you have to scan a lot more data.

**Important** At the time of writing (June 2017), you cannot safely use S3 as a direct destination of spark RDD/dataframe queries (i.e. `save()`) calls. See [Cloud Integration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/cloud-integration.md) for an explanation. Write to HDFS then copy